# Accessing application code from overridden Tomcat class

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, tomcat7, libraries

I'm currently creating my own [JDBCRealm](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/RealmBase.html) and more specifically, I'm overriding the Authenticate method. The override was no problem, and I got it to work using SHA authentication.

The problems starting arising when I needed to access a different column that isn't covered by Tomcat's own methods, like `getPassword(username)` and `getPrincipal(username)`.

I have a Hibernate method that retrieves a user based on their username and it looks like:

```
UsersDTO user = UsersDAO.getUser(username);
```

The problem is, that because the code is part of the Tomcat library and not the application, calling the method doesn't work. It throws no exceptions and nothing gets logged to *catalina.out*, it just presents me with a **500 HTTP error**.

I have tried numerous things, but I'm at a loss at the moment. Can anyone shed a light on my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call classes loaded by the app classloader from classes loaded by the server classloader.

You should deploy your jars in a way that all the invocations are done between classes loaded by the same classloader, or from classes loaded by a lower level classloader to classes loaded by a higher level classloader.

Take a look at this. It's related to Weblogic, but the same concepts apply to Tomcat.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm

Comment: Then how would I go about accessing other columns in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is implemented with Apache Commons Logging library. So with proper implementation of that logging library in your code, tomcat should be able to log your error properly.
see reference [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)

Comment: I know how the logging works, it's not working though, pretty sure it's related to what @Andres is saying.